# print number from 1 to 10 after every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to print number after every n number of seconds and based on few conditions i am changing the timer as well as i am stopping the print function. i have done like this --

```
var myfunc = {
    value   : 1,
    running : false,
    timer   : 1000,
    start   : function(){
        this.running = true;
        clearInterval(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            myfunc.execute(myfunc);
        }, myfunc.timer);

    },
    execute : function(){
        if(!this.running) return false;

        console.log( 'Currently at -- ' + (this.value++) );

        if (this.value > 5 ){
            this.changetiming();
        }

        if (this.value > 10 ){
            this.stop();
            return;
        }else{
            this.start();
        }

    },
    changetiming : function(){
        this.timer = 3000;
    },
    stop : function(){
        this.running = false;
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
};

myfunc.start();
```

Now i want to know what is wrong with following code --

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    print(i);
}


function print(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: Use interval as `i * 2000`

Comment: Thanks Satpal.. Second code is working now. can you please explain why i have to multiply? what is happening there if you consider my second code

Comment: @AdityaKumar when setTimeout execute inside the print function, it will move the callback function into the async task and attaches the 2000ms timer on each function at the same time. This is similar print all number at the same time. If you know the event loop, you will understand the details behind the scene.

Comment: I was checking same thing and come across [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/thrown-for-a-loop-understanding-for-loops-and-timeouts-in-javascript-558d8255d8a4/) blog it is really helpful to understand this logic.

Answer (score 9):

here is the right way and easy way to do this in ES6+:

```js
const printNumbersForEvery2Sec = (n)=>{
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      setTimeout( () =>{
        console.log(i)
      }, i * 2000)
    }
}
printNumbersForEvery2Sec(10);
```

by multiplying `i` , each setTimeout() to be delayed 2 to 20 seconds (2000 x 1, 2000 x 2…) respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the question "Why does this JavaScript code

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    print(i);
}

function print(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    },2000);
}
```

print out the values 1 through 10 at once, after 2 seconds have elapsed?" has been asked before.

It is a common mistake.

What you are doing is calling `print` 10 times. Each call to print takes only a few microseconds. Why? Because it just calls `setTimeout`. Executing `setTimeout` takes only a few microseconds to complete. All the call does is *schedule* something to take place in the future. So within a few microseconds you have scheduled 10 things to take place at about 2 seconds in the future. All the schedulings happen at about the same time. So all the console logs take place at about the same time, two seconds after you scheduled them.

See Satapal's comment to your question for a nice way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

**#easiestway**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    print(i);
}

function print(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    },i*2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using IIFE, Clouser, and Global Scoping

```
(function(numbers){
  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(console.log, i*2000, i+1)
    })(i);
  }
})(new Array(10))
```

OR IIFE and Local Scoping

```
(function(numbers){
  for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    setTimeout(console.log, i*2000, i+1)
  }
})(new Array(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
  setTimeout( () => { console.log(i) }, i * 1000 );
}
```

Why we are not able to print 0 to 10 no with the help of var?
Why we are able to do with let?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Kajal landage.  I edited your post to fix the code block formatting but I wasn't sure how to help clarify your two questions.  Could you please update your response to clarify your questions?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31111818)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const promiseMaker = (val) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(val)
    }, 2000)
  })
}
const printFrom1to10With2SecDelay = async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    try {
      let val = await promiseMaker(i);
      console.log(val)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
printFrom1to10With2SecDelay()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

````
const printNumbersForEvery2Sec = (n)=>{
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) setTimeout(console.log, i * 1000,i) 
}

printNumbersForEvery2Sec(10);```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeout of javascript

```js
function timer(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, i * n);
    }
}

timer(2000);
```

In the above code timing is not coded so you can decide how much interval you want.

Answer (score 0):

A more generalised solution:

```js
function printNumbers(start, end, delay=1){
  const interval = delay*1000
  for(let i=start; i<=end; i++){
      setTimeout(console.log, (i-start)*interval, i)
  }
}

printNumbers(3, 10, 2) // firstNumber, lastNumber, timeInSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  }, (i * 2000) )
}
```

Far best! and easy solution... Checkout snippet...

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  }, (i * 2000) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const RandomUnderHundredNumber = (min,max) => {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max); 
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; /*min and max numbers are included */
}
let inter
const testFunction = () => {
inter = setInterval(() => console.log(RandomUnderHundredNumber(0,99)), 1000) // generate number between 0 and 99 every 1 sec  
}
testFunction();
setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(inter); }, 5000); /* clear interval after 5 sec delay (optional) */
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const printNumbersForEvery2Sec = (n)=>{
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      setTimeout( () =>{
        console.log(i)
      }, i * 2000)
    }
}
printNumbersForEvery2Sec(10);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There are `two` solution to this problem.

> 1. Using `let` keyword, local scope.

```js
const printNumbers = (n) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 2000);
      
    }
    
    
}
printNumbers(5);
```

> 2. Using `var` keyword, functional scope with the help of `closures`.

> Wrap the setTimeout function with another function which has the value of the variable at that instance. Which console's log the correct value.

> Example is shown below.

```js
 const printNumbers = (n) => {
      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          
          function helper(num){
             setTimeout( () => {
               console.log(num);
             }, num * 2000);
          }
          
          helper(i);
          
        }
        
        
 }
 printNumbers(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print 1 to 10 every 1 second using IIFE -

```
(function(){
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        setTimeout(console.log,i*1000,i)
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code will print 1 after 1 second, 2 after 2 seconds and so on.....
const fibNum = (n) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum = sum + i;
  return sum;
};

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
  }, fibNum(i + 1) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: This code will print 1 after a delay of 1 second, 2 after a delay of 2 seconds and so on till 5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).