# How can i print number in regular interval through setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var i=0;
function counter(){
    for( i;i<100;i++){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(i);
        },2000)
    }
}

counter();
```

i want to print i in interval of 2 second but it prints immediately

Each call to print takes only a few microseconds. Why? Because it just calls setTimeout. Executing setTimeout takes only a few microseconds to complete. All the call does is schedule something to take place in the future. So within a few microseconds you have scheduled 10 things to take place at about 2 seconds in the future. All the schedulings happen at about the same time. So all the console logs take place at about the same time, two seconds after you scheduled them.

> How can i print in interval of 2 second using for loop?

1

2

3

4

... in 2 second delay through for loop

Comment: You can get rid of `var i = 0` and change your for loop to `for( i = 0; i < 100; i++){`

Comment: i needed that i further in another function bro so i declared it globally btw thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling the function recursively from inside the setTimeout? That way, once the setTimeout triggers it calls the function

Comment: yes not working

Comment: hmm.. I see your question is asking about `setInterval()`, but your code shows `setTimeout()`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const printNumbersForEvery2Sec = (n) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
    }, i * 2000)
  }
}
printNumbersForEvery2Sec(10);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016211/print-number-from-1-to-10-after-every-2-seconds)

Comment: Why am I getting constant 2 second interval when i run this? If somehow that IS the correct output, then what is the point of passing i*2000 instead of just 2000 into setTimeout function??

Answer (score 1):

Use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), like this:

```js
var i=0;
var intervalID;
    
function printAndIncrement()
{
    // Stop interval procedure when "var i" reach to 100.

    if (i > 100)
    {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        return;
    }

    console.log(i);
    i++;
 }
    
 intervalID = setInterval(printAndIncrement, 1000);
```

Comment: i want to print 1 2 3 4 5 6... 100 in 1 second delay through for loop

Comment: You want to print from 1 to 100 every one second and after that reset again to 1 or just stops?

Comment: 1 delay 2 delay 3 delay 4 delay...  100 stop using for loop and setTimeout thanks

Comment: Why you want to use a **for loop** and **setTimeout()**, i just updated to accomplish the same with **setInterval()**

Comment: i am using this concept inside forEach loop thanks for your time but it's solved above

Answer (score 1):

> How can i print in interval of 2 second?

'Drift' due to CPU time is a consideration.

If your use case is running code spaced 2 seconds apart **minimum**, use `setTimeout()`:

```js
let ctr = 1

const fn = () => {
  console.log(ctr++)
  setTimeout(fn, 2000) // set the next run
  }

setTimeout(fn, 2000) // set 1st run
```

If your use case is running code spaced 2 seconds apart **maximum**, use `setInterval()`:

```js
let ctr = 1

const fn = () => console.log(ctr++)

setInterval(fn, 2000)
```

More on JS CPU Timer drift here: https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter(){
for( let i=0;i<100;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(i);
    },2000)
}
}counter();
```

Just change `var` to `let`

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. 
Explain why this is an answer to the question.